My plugin won't run created with Node.js Stream Deck SDK and RobotJS
I would like to make a more advanced keyboard and mouse emulator to alternate the built-in actions.
Started from a plugin template.
Built it without any changes and it worked.
Then installed robotjs module and rollup plugin to pack robotjs.node file.
Added robot.keyTap() into main script's onKeyDown event.
After that, the plugin stops working.
Setup:
npm install -g @elgato/cli
streamdeck create

Module Installation:
npm i robotjs
npm i --save-dev rollup-plugin-natives

rollup.config.mjs
(Added some lines to pack robotjs.node file, and didn't touch other parts.)
// ...
import nativePlugin from 'rollup-plugin-natives'
// ...
const config = {
        // ...
    plugins: [
        nativePlugin
        (
            {
                copyTo: `./${sdPlugin}/lib`,
            }
        )
    ]
};


...\src\actions\increment-counter.ts
(A template script I've got when run "streamdeck create".)
import { action, KeyDownEvent, DialRotateEvent, SingletonAction, WillAppearEvent } from "@elgato/streamdeck";
import * as robot from 'robotjs'

@action({ UUID: "com.user.testplugin.increment" })
export class IncrementCounter extends SingletonAction<CounterSettings> {
    async onWillAppear(ev: WillAppearEvent<CounterSettings>): Promise<void>
    {
        let count = 0;
        await ev.action.setSettings({ count });
        return ev.action.setTitle(`${count}`);
    }
    async onKeyDown(ev: KeyDownEvent<CounterSettings>): Promise<void> {
        let count = ev.payload.settings.count ?? 0;
        count++;
        robot.keyTap('enter'); // <-- .

        await ev.action.setSettings({ count });
        await ev.action.setTitle(`count}`);
    }
}

type CounterSettings = {
    count: number;
};

Calling robot methods such as keyTap() will not run the plugin.
Even it was in try{}, script won't reach to catch(error){...}.
So, I cannot debug the plugin and cannot get error message.
If the plugin runs, "0" should be displayed on a button, but nothing displayed.
A warning sign ⚠️ displayed on it when press it.
What is wrong?
I am not familiar with typescript and rollup.
Please help.
Environment:
Windows 10 Home 64bit
Stream Deck 6.6.1
NodeJS v18.18.0


It's probably too late, but I have ran into a similar problem:
RollupError: node_modules/robotjs/build/Release/robotjs.node (1:2): Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
I was able to resolve this issue by editing rollup.config.mjs and declaring robotjs as an external dependency.
Like this:
const config = {
  input: "...",
  output: { ... },
  plugins: [ ... ],
  external: ["robotjs"],
};

export default config;

I am new to stream deck plugins, node and rollup as well. But I hope this helps if anyone stumbles across this issue again^^
